# SVG use tag and ReactJS

Tags: svg, sprite, reactjs

So normally to include most of my SVG icons that require simple styling, I do:

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="/svg/svg-sprite#my-icon" />
</svg>
```

Now I have been playing with ReactJS as of late evaluating it as a possible component in my new front-end development stack however I noticed that in its list of supported tags/attributes, neither `use` or `xlink:href` are supported.

Is it possible to use svg sprites and load them in this way in ReactJS?

Comment: For future visitors, you can now use `<use xlinkHref="/svg/svg-sprite#my-icon" />`.

Comment: `xlink:href` is deprecated, now supposed to just use `href` -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href

Comment: @MattGreer As of 2018, Safari still needs `xlink:href` so we still need to use it. Actual web applications need to either use the common denominator of browser features, or implement specific workarounds / polyfills.

Comment: I'm just adding this comment to help others who search for this error, which was solved by Jon Surrell's answer below: `Property 'xlink' does not exist on type 'SVGProps<SVGImageElement>`

Comment: Hey, maybe accept a different answer?  Community seems to be agreed about that.  Just a helpful suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**Update september 2018**: this solution is deprecated, read [Jon’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26815738/svg-use-tag-and-reactjs/26822815#32994814) instead.

--

React doesn’t support all SVG tags as you say, there is a list of supported tags [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html). They are working on wider support, f.ex in [this ticket](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1657).

A common workaround is to inject HTML instead for non-supported tags, f.ex:

```
render: function() {
    var useTag = '<use xlink:href="/svg/svg-sprite#my-icon" />';
    return <svg dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: useTag }} />;
}
```

Comment: No, don't use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. You can use `xlinkHref` as mentioned below.

Comment: Author should probably should remove this as the accepted answer

Answer (score 311):

MDN says that `xlink:href` [is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href) in favor of `href`. You should be able to use the `href` attribute directly. The example below includes both versions.

As of **React 0.14**, `xlink:href` is available via React as the property `xlinkHref`. It is mentioned as one of the "notable enhancements" in the [release notes](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#notable-enhancements) for 0.14.

```html
<!-- REACT JSX: -->
<svg>
  <use xlinkHref='/svg/svg-sprite#my-icon' />
</svg>

<!-- RENDERS AS: -->
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="/svg/svg-sprite#my-icon"></use>
</svg>
```

**Update 2018-06-09:** Added info about `href` vs `xlink:href` attributes and updated example to include both. [Thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26815738/svg-use-tag-and-reactjs/32994814#comment88770218_32994814) [@devuxer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129164/devuxer)

**Update 3**: At time of writing, React master SVG properties can be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/dom/shared/SVGDOMPropertyConfig.js).

**Update 2**: It appears that *all* svg attributes should now be available via react (see merged [svg attribute PR](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/5714)).

<del>**Update 1**: You may want to keep an eye on the [svg related issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1657#issuecomment-155956187) on GitHub for additional SVG support landing. There are developments in the works.</del>

## Demo:

```js
const svgReactElement = (
  <svg
    viewBox="0 0 1340 667"
    width="100"
    height="100"
  >
    <image width="667" height="667" href="https://i.imgur.com/w7GCRPb.png"/>
    { /* Deprecated xlink:href usage */ }
    <image width="667" height="667" x="673" xlinkHref="https://i.imgur.com/w7GCRPb.png"/>
  </svg>
);

var resultHtml = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(svgReactElement);
document.getElementById('render-result-html').innerHTML = escapeHtml(resultHtml);

ReactDOM.render(svgReactElement, document.getElementById('render-result') );

function escapeHtml(unsafe) { return unsafe.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/"/g, "&quot;").replace(/'/g, "&#039;"); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.1/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.1/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.1/umd/react-dom-server.browser.development.js"></script>

<h2>Render result of rendering:</h2>
<pre>&lt;svg
  viewBox=&quot;0 0 1340 667&quot;
  width=&quot;100&quot;
  height=&quot;100&quot;
&gt;
  &lt;image width=&quot;667&quot; height=&quot;667&quot; href=&quot;https://i.imgur.com/w7GCRPb.png&quot;/&gt;
  { /* Deprecated xlink:href usage */ }
  &lt;image width=&quot;667&quot; height=&quot;667&quot; x=&quot;673&quot; xlinkHref=&quot;https://i.imgur.com/w7GCRPb.png&quot;/&gt;
&lt;/svg&gt;</pre>

<h2><code>ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup()</code> output:</h2>
<pre id="render-result-html"></pre>
<h2><code>ReactDOM.render()</code> output:</h2>
<div id="render-result"></div>
```

Comment: > Update 25 Dec 2015: It appears that all svg attributes should now be available via react (see merged svg attribute PR). 
Is there a standard way to use these svg attributes? Will they all be camel cased like in the case of xlink:href => xlinkHref ?

Comment: @majorBummer take a look [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/dff05beeff9562647950461830ce42d484ca55fa/src/renderers/dom/shared/SVGDOMPropertyConfig.js#L58-L83)

Comment: this really needs to be the correct answer, especially when the current chosen answer recommends dangerouslySetInnerHTML, which is, well, dangerous

Comment: According to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href), `xlink:href` has been deprecated, and the recommendation is to use `href` without the namespace prefix. (Note, however, if you're using TypeScript, the typings haven't yet been updated to reflect this.)

Comment: At the time of writing, xlink:href is supported in Safari, but href is not.

Comment: `<textPath href={"#line"} xlinkHref={"#line"}>` has been working for me so far, but not sure what side affect it will have with each browser when they drop it. Hopefully they will just ignore it.

Comment: xlink:href deprecated for SVG 2.0, but it is still a work in progress with no full browser implementation, also old browsers do not support SVG 2

Answer (score 10):

If you encounter `xlink:href`, then you can get the equivalent in ReactJS by removing the colon and camelcasing the added text: `xlinkHref`.

You'll probably eventually be using other namespace-tags in SVG, like `xml:space`, etc..  The same rule applies to them (i.e., `xml:space` becomes `xmlSpace`).

Answer (score 6):

As already said in Jon Surrell's answer, use-tags are supported now. If you are not using JSX, you can implement it like this:

```
React.DOM.svg( { className: 'my-svg' },
    React.createElement( 'use', { xlinkHref: '/svg/svg-sprite#my-icon' }, '' )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I created a little helper that works around this issue: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg-use

first `npm i react-svg-use -S` then simply

```
import Icon from 'react-svg-use'

React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <Icon id='car' color='#D71421' />
    )
  }
})
```

and this will then generate the following markup

```
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="#car" style="fill:#D71421;"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: Dude, you must be commended with +500 points for this!

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with showing SVG in Gutenberg block, by referencing it with `xlink:href`. We used `xlinkHref` property in react, but after compiling, instead to render as `xlink:href` it was rendered to `xlinkhref`, and SVG was not displayed. After a lot of examining, I found out that `xlink:href` is deprecated (although it worked if we add it in html, or directly in chrome dev tools), and that `href` should be used instead. So after changing it to `href` it worked.

"SVG 2 removed the need for the xlink namespace, so instead of xlink:href you should use href." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href

This is the code I used

**SVG file**

```
<svg id="svg-source" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <symbol id="svg-arrow-accordion" viewBox="0 0 15 24" fill="none">
        <path id="Path_1662" data-name="Path 1662" d="M15.642,14.142h-3V1.5H0v-3H15.642Z" transform="translate(2 2) rotate(45)" fill="currentColor"></path>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

React file

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="15" height="24">
<use href="#svg-arrow-accordion"></use>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is svg Component.

```
const SvgComponent = () => {
    return <svg width="0" height="0">
        <defs>
            <symbol id="test" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                <line x1='0' y1='50' x2='100' y2='50' strokeWidth='8' stroke="#000" />
            </symbol>
        </defs>
    </svg>
}

export default SvgComponent
```

use component

```
import SvgComponent from './SvgComponent';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <SvgComponent/>
      <svg>
        <use xlinkHref="#test"></use>
      </svg>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).