# How to use xlinkHref on svg tag <a> using Typescript and React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, xlink

I am trying to make my SVG focusable, by implementing [this simple and elegant solution](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/ZQWxZV).

I am using Typescript and React, here is my code:

```
return (
  <g {...propsWbsComponent} >
    <a xlinkHref={"#"}>
      <rect  {...propsWbsComponentBox} />
    </a>

    <text {...propsWbsId} >
      {props.wbsComponentId}
    </text>
  </g>
}
```

I am getting the error message:

> error TS2339: Property 'xlinkHref' does not exist on type 'HTMLProps'

I am not sure where to look, if it's a Typescript issue, React missing svg attributes (although xlinkHref is now part of React) or something else.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is fantastic @RobertLongson! I wouldn't have thought of that, and as a bonus I can now use TAB to navigate my svg. Thanks a lot. Could you write a short answer so I can validate it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG can do this natively if you set a [tabindex](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#tabindexattribute) attribute. This works the same as the [HTML attribute of the same name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex).

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to set `xlinkHref` on an `a` tag, which is not supported. The `xlinkHref` property should be used on a `<use>` tag instead.

You can read up on the allowed defs here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14893

[SVG use tag and ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26815738/svg-use-tag-and-reactjs)

Comment: I saw these posts, but I don't understand how to use `<use>` to make my `<rect>` clickable the same way as the example (see the hyperlink). Could you show me a short example?